# Get list of running windows applications using python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I want to return only those applications which get listed under "Apps" category in the Windows task manager and NOT all of the running processes. The below script returns all processes which I don't want. How can I modify this code as per my requirements?

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'WMIC PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use *powershell* instead of *WMIC* to get the desired list of applications:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowTitle } | select Description'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    if line.rstrip():
        # only print lines that are not empty
        # decode() is necessary to get rid of the binary string (b')
        # rstrip() to remove `\r\n`
        print(line.decode().rstrip())
```

### Getting an empty table?

Please note that on some systems this results in an empty table as the description seems to be empty. In that case you might want to try a different column, such as `ProcessName`, resulting in the following command:

```
cmd = 'powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowTitle } | select ProcessName'
```

### Need more columns/information in the output?

If you want to have **more information**, for example *process id* or *path* tidying up the output needs a bit more effort.

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowTitle } | select Description,Id,Path'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    if not line.decode()[0].isspace():
        print(line.decode().rstrip())
```

The output of `cmd` is text formatted as a table. Unfortunately it returns more than just the applications we need, so we need to tidy up a bit. All applications that are wanted have an entry in the *Description* column, thus we just check if the first character is whitespace or not.

This is, what the original table would look like (before the `isspace()` if clause):

```
Description                                    Id Path
-----------                                    -- ----
                                              912
                                             9124
                                            11084
Microsoft Office Excel                       1944 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE
```

Comment: if i wanted to close one of those programs using python how would i be able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

For cross-platform solutions, now you can use `pywinctl` or `pygetwindow`. `pywinctl` is a fork of `pygetwindow` with enhancement in MacOS and Linux environments. Sample codes below:

```
import pywinctl as pwc
from time import sleep

mytitle = 'notepad'
while True:
    try:
        titles = pwc.getAllTitles()
        if mytitle not in titles:
            break
        print('Waiting for current window to be closed...')
        sleep(3)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```